# Find multiple values with one where condition in one column mysql

Tags: php, mysql

This is the table of my profile:

```html
<table border="1">
<tr>
<td>Name</td>
<td>Skills</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>John Doe</td>
<td>php-development, css, html, ajax</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Jane Doe</td>
<td>xml, jquery, ajax, php-development</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Markinson Zuckerberg</td>
<td>html, php-development, ajax, magento</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

I'm trying to filter using get method from SQL:

```html
<pre>$sql= "SELECT distinct * FROM `profile` WHERE status='1'";

if(isset($_GET['services']) && $_GET['services']!="") :
    $sql.=" AND services LIKE '%".implode("%','%",$_GET['services'])."%'";
endif;</pre>
```

I tried above code for filtering but it's taking concatenating sql query as

```
SELECT distinct * 
FROM profile 
WHERE status='1' 
AND services LIKE '%affiliate-marketing%','%ajax%' 
ORDER BY pid DESC
```

Any solutions?

Comment: Add each `services` term individually and use a prepared statement to avoid sql injection.

Comment: avoid concatenation and use PDO prepared statements

Comment: I know but I need to use concatenation as I'm using more condition from the get method @jeroe

Comment: try RLIKE 'tom|smith|larry'; this one make more easy

Comment: So? Treat each term as if it is a different input then.

Comment: SELECT distinct * 
FROM profile 
WHERE status='1' 
AND services  
RLIKE 'affiliate-marketing|ajax';
ORDER BY pid DESC

Comment: @KaliDass thnx... ur solution work....143

Comment: @KaliDass RLIKE is using OR condition '|' what if I want to use AND Condition?

Answer (score 2):

You can't use `LIKE '%something%', '%somethingelse%'`, that syntax is not valid. You need to use the `OR` keyword to list your filtering possibilities.

Assuming `$_GET['services']` is an array :

```
<?php

$_GET['services'] = array('affiliate-marketing', 'ajax');
$sql = ''; // just for output purposes

$services_like = array() ;
foreach ($_GET['services'] as $service) {
    $services_like[] = ' service LIKE "%' . $service . '%" ';
}
$services_like_string = implode (' OR ', $services_like);

$sql .= 'AND ( ' . $services_like_string . ' ) ';

echo $sql; // echoes : AND ( service LIKE "%affiliate-marketing%" OR service LIKE "%ajax%" ) 
?>
```